# Difference between else and elsif in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In this code, if I pass "my name is bobby li" to `longest_word` it returns "bobby". But if I choose `else` instead of `elsif`, it will return "li". Can someone explain?

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  words = sentence.split(" ")
  longest_word = nil
  word_idx = 0

  while word_idx < words.length
    current_word = words[word_idx]

    if longest_word == nil
      longest_word = current_word
    elsif longest_word.length < current_word.length
      longest_word = current_word
    end

    word_idx += 1
 end

 return longest_word
end
```

Comment: The difference is that `else` doesn't accept a condition. So your length check there is simply ignored in that case.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Well, it's still evaluated, but it's not a condition. It's interpreted as just another part of the body of the `else` clause. (Which, since it doesn't have any side-effects and its return value is ignored, doesn't do anything, so in some sense it *is* ignored.)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really what you asked, but I hope it's helpful.

It struck me that you're doing a lot of unnecessary work in your function. Below are a couple of potential alternatives.

### First Approach: Keep the Iterator

```
  def longest_word(sentence)
    longest_word = nil

    sentence.split(" ").each do |current_word|
      longest_word ||= current_word
      longest_word = current_word if current_word.length > longest_word.length
    end

    longest_word
  end
```

Here, using `sentence.split(" ").each do |current_word|` lets you skip all that `idx` stuff that you're doing.

Now, in you code where you say:

```
  if longest_word == nil
    longest_word = current_word
    ...
  end
```

I'd suggest you use:

```
  if longest_word.nil?
    longest_word = current_word
    ...
  end
```

Or better yet:

```
  unless longest_word
    longest_word = current_word
    ...
  end
```

If you go one step further, you could get rid of your first `if` statement by using the trailing conditional:

```
  longest_word = current_word unless longest_word
```

The more idiomatic way of saying this in ruby (IMO) is:

```
  longest_word ||= current_word
```

(Google 'ruby conditional assignment' for detail on `||=`).

After that, you could say:

```
  if current_word.length > longest_word.length
    longest_word = current_word
  end
```

But again I think it's cleaner to use the trailing conditional:

```
  longest_word = current_word if current_word.length > longest_word.length
```

This approach saves you seven lines of code - which may not seem like a lot. But, over time it piles up. More importantly, I think maybe it is easier to read and understand.

### Second Approach: Ditch the Iterator

Instead of all the above, you could simply say:

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  sentence.split(" ")
          .sort{|x,y| x.length <=> y.length}
          .last
end
```

This basically says, "sort the word array in ascending order of length and then return the last element".

Personally, I'd write it like:

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  sentence.split(" ").sort{|x,y| x.length <=> y.length}.last
end
```

You save twelve lines (which I like doing so I can see more on screen at once instead of having to scroll my code).

No conditionals. No assignments. No loops. Just clean and readable ruby goodness.

Anyway, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

During the first iteration, `longest_word` is nil and so the if condition will be executed. If you use `else`, in the remaining iterations of the loop, the `if` condition will never evaluate to true since its not nil anymore.

So, no matter whether the `current_word`'s length is greater than `longest_word`, it would just update the `current_word` as the `longest_word`. As a result, you will always get the last word as the `longest_word` if you `else` instead of `elsif`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `elsif`, you are always checking the condition whether the `current_word` length is greater than the `longest_word` found so far or not, and update the `longest_word` only if the condition evaluates to true i.e `current_word` is indeed longer than `longest_word`. So answer is "bobby".

But if you use `else`, then we just update the `longest_word` as the `current_word` irrespective of whether `current_word` is longer than `longest_word` or not. So, ans is words[last_index] i.e "li"